# Inserting text in piechart ArcGIS

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, text, chart

I want to insert a names or percent text into each category in a piechart. I have googled and cant find a way to do this in arcgis pro. Is there a solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: 1. Have you looked into what your label (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/labeling-basics.htm) options are when using pie charts? and 2. Have you considered the readability of this already busy map if you were to add label text on the pie charts. As it is nearly half your map is covered by the pie charts, and then each pie chart has ten different slices. It might be worth considering if labeled pie chart symbology is actually the best way to convey this information to your audience.